# Is there a way to use the IPad 2018 with both a midi controller and audio out?

Tags: audio, usb, midi

The iPad Pro 2018 has a single USB-C port. I have a dongle (USB-C => Audio) that lets me use headphones, I have a dongle (USB-C => USB-A) that lets me plug in a MIDI Keyboard.

What I want is to be able to do both.

Devices like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07KPXGWKK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00) ought to be ideal but this one only lets power through the USB-C port.

There are also a number of large hubs, but they often have poor ratings related to the audio output quality.

Any recommendations?